# Connect ComboBox and Submit Button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox

I am trying to connect some command line commands to a simple `ComboBox` with a button that executes the commands. I am having difficulty connecting the "submit" or execute button with the ComboBox items.

I am using Visual Studios and am selecting -Visual Basics WPF

Any help is appreaciated!

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="332,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Height="22" RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.458">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Ping 1.1.1.1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Ping google.com"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Above is Xaml
Below is xaml.vb

```
Class MainWindow
Private Sub showSelectedButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim selectedIndex As Integer
    selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedItem As Object
    selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem

End Sub

Private Sub comboBox1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles comboBox1.SelectionChanged

End Sub



Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim selectedItem As Object = comboBox1.SelectedItem
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It depends what your selected item type. If this is just string, you can do `Dim str As String =  CType(comboBox1.SelectedItem, String)`

Answer (score 1):

in the button1_click you want to do something like this

```
Dim selectedItem as object = comboBox.selecteditem
```

However you should probably look in to some more of the MVVM model to understand that WPF really works better with bindings, but this is the "quick" answer given you already have setup the code behind.

Comment: I updated the above code- Now I am not sure how to set the commands to each selection? i.e. selection 1 may be ping 1.1.1.1

Comment: I am open to using a different approach if that would be easier.

Comment: So if you want ping something on your command ... thats really another question but if you add 1.1.1.1 to you combobox then in your command_click you would do something like 'my.computer.ping(combobox.selectedtext)'

Comment: I updated the above code, does that look right? I cant seem to test it as the button doesnt have anything to do yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your xaml for design of user interface you do not attach any event with the objects. Add events first with objects then write codes to do any jobs.
For Button 1
Button x:Name="button1" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="308,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
Click=Button_Click/
Now if you click this button then it can execute Button_Click procedure, which one you already wrote.
Like this you must have add SelectionChanged event with ComboBox in xaml syntax to run SelectionChanged event.
Hope it can help you.